# How to explain to my manager the importance of separation of concerns?

Tags: php, html, front-end, separation-of-concerns

I'm an extremely novice web programmer working at a 2 person shop building websites, and we're in the process of writing a simple website template system in PHP from scratch. My manager is entirely self taught. He has been insisting that we put our HTML directly quoted in variables, mixing our back end code with the front end stuff.

```
$foo = "<html>
        <body>
            <div class=\"bar\">" . $bar . "</div>
        </body>
        </html>";

echo $foo;
```

He claims that it is easier to work with this way. I insisted that we should at least use PHP tags in our HTML, rather than the HTML in the PHP.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="bar"><?php echo $bar; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like this is a real pain in the ass to read and it just looks like a mess. I think it would be a lot easier to separate the logic from the presentation, but he is certain that his way is best. How can I explain the importance of this so that he will understand? I can't put it into words, exactly.

EDIT: Think you guys could leave a comment when you're down voting me? I have no idea how to fix my question if you just down vote it and leave without suggesting improvements.

Comment: Neither example is good. Use a proper templating language (such as Twig), and preferably a framework such as Symfony2. Let me guess: neither example is secured against XSS?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that those are available but that's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: I suspect a knee-jerk reaction to you complaining about how it looks, which actually isn't entirely off-base given that one big benefit on the front end where we're mixing JS, CSS and HTML, is legibility. It's not exactly the best argument for being a stickler for separation of concerns however.

Comment: Which is why I am here to understand the actual argument for SoC. I can't quite put it into words, but I know that it's the best way to do it. I know it's cleaner and more logical, but I can't exactly say why. It just makes sense to me. Plus I know it offers better performance in some circumstances because the server is not reading the HTML when it's outside of the PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons:

- The designer and PHP programmer can't work on their respective concerns at the same time. That means high potential for scenarios where one person will have to wait for the other to be done or if you're actually using version control run into a merge conflict all of which needlessly take time, which costs $$$s
- It limits options for a white-labeling approach where you have similar front ends being served by mostly the same back-end. That may unexpectedly reduce the value of the app to a given customer who decides to split their brand leading to a decision to not use you again which costs you $$$s
- Similarly you may find your markup is almost perfect for another project requiring only new CSS and some minor tweaks and find replaces but bad-news-bears, it's hoplessly spliced and intertwined with your server-side code rather than only at spots where the server actually adds conent so you won't have that option costing you more time which as we know turns into $$$s
- It flies in the face of almost universal convention, meaning even if you're sure you're right and everybody else is wrong, they're still going to think your firm is inept when they're devs or future devs see that code which costs you $$$s
- It does look terrible. On the client-side where you can have several languages and lord knows how many silly things from templating and down-compiling/help-you-not-suck-at-css dependencies, we keep 'em separated for legibility/sanity. Stop by the JavaScript chat room on SE and ask folks there how many have ADD. We freaking all do. Keep it clean so our heads don't explode. Otherwise it would take us longer to remember what the crap 3-5 languages we were trying to process simultaneously and understand what we're looking at which means it takes us longer which costs you $$$s
- You're not alone among UI devs. Very few of us would consider that no biggie. I get pissed when opening and closing tags aren't found in the same damn template. Harder to attract and keep enthusiastic talent when you decide your way is better than widely acknowledged convention which yes, does indeed cost more $$$s

Note the pattern. Relate the stuff you care about to how it results in costs. He likely won't give a damn if he's resisted as much accidental knowledge of best practices as he has in the process of learning how to build a website with PHP, but it's usually the best/only way if there is one.

Comment: This is more what I was looking for. I attempted to explain things using some of what you offered, but it didn't seem to get through. Thanks for your efforts, regardless.

Comment: @tbowman Then I recommend plan B. Learn more about JavaScript and CSS than anybody you've ever worked with or are likely to. You may discover many new flavors of people making decisions they aren't qualified to make but it won't ever take more than 0-4 weeks to find a new job.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this as follows: you have two separate concerns, the view and the application logic.  Simply remind him that, since view code and application code are all mixed in together, changes to the view could (hint: at some point they will) break the application logic.  Similarly, changes to the application logic could mess up the view.  That is probably the best rationale for separation of concerns -- code isolation.

Another possible argument is that, at some point, the web applications you are developing may need additional front-ends (think customized mobile site, REST/XML interface, etc.)  With application logic and view code all mergled (merged and mangled) together, adding *additional* view technologies becomes a nightmare.

Finally, how does he intend to test the application code separate from the view (or does he see the need for unit testing)?  With cleanly separated code, testing becomes much easier.  That is all I can think of off the top of my head.  Hope everything works out for you.